# Angle brackets sublime text 2

Tags: keyboard, sublimetext2

I have problem with angle brackets in Sublime Text. I used `alt+keysNextToM` to insert `<` and `>`, but now it is not working, it only works when I set the document-syntax to "plain text". Please help me, I can't work without these keys.

In CSS or HTML source `Alt+>` or `Alt+<` jumps through code, but I want to insert `<` or `>` rather than navigating through the document.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After the last update I couldn't make angle brackets. Removing ZenCoding fixed that. I wasn't really using it so it wasn't a problem to get rid of it.

I case you have the same problem and need ZenCoding go through the key bindings, there's probably something there to unbind :)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with another module killing right <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> which inserted `[` bracket ...
You can restore this default key binding, or reset the key binding indirectly.

By redefining in it your user key bindings as command that inserts a character you want:
(modifying the module key binding file would get overridden on update)

`{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+f"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "["}  },`

yours would likely be

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+,"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "<"}  },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+."], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": ">"}  },
```